# Angular value selector

Tags: javascript, angular, консоль

имею код который принимает значение из родительского класса

```
  @Input() userArray:{id:number,name:string}[]=[

 ];
```

вопрос в том что как передать значение

```
<app-child [userArray]="{'id':0,'name':'Майкл'}"></app-child>
```

так выдает ошибку пишет что поле id  не существует

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что на входе вы ожидаете массив, а передаете объект? **[userArray]="[{'id':0,'name':'Майкл'}]"**

Comment: да вот не уточнил извинте,я хочу передать массив из объектов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте передавать так

```
<app-child [userArray]="[{'id':0,'name':'Майкл'}]"></app-child>
```